# Dynamically Codeigniter Image Upload Rename

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am uploading multiple dynamic images with codeigniter with the following code.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {   

    $imagePrefix = time();                                  

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key))
    {
        echo $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
        return '';
    }
    else
    {
        $imagename = $imagePrefix.$value['name'];
        $insertImage = $this->db->query("Insert into `tbl_event_imges` (`iEventID`,`vImage`) values ('".$insertId."','".$imagename."')");
    }
}
```

When I upload an image to the specific folder this works fine; the issue is if a user uploads an image having same name, then it will automatically rename the image and upload to the folder, but what I want is to rename it by adding `$imagePrefix` that I have added in `else` part of the code and then want to upload the image with this name. But this is not working with me..

Any suggestion please?

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Nope,i am trying to rename uploading file with use of key,,but not working

Comment: Codeigniter upload library is only for single file uploads only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide configuration preferences to your upload function like so:

```
$imagePrefix = time(); 
$imagename = $imagePrefix.$value['name'];

$this->load->library('upload');

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['file_name'] = $imagename; // set the name here

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key)){
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

Source: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=file%20upload#setting-preferences

Answer (score 0):

Just alternative, you can use CI's rename function to rename after file uploaded.

```
$image = $this->upload->data();
$file_path = $image ['file_path'];
$file = $image ['full_path'];
$file_ext = $image['file_ext'];
$final_file_name = time() . $image['file_name'] . $file_ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

only add below code and it run successfully and also set `encrypt_name` to `false`

```
$path = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$newName = "Add any name".".".pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$config['file_name'] = $newName; 
$config['encrypt_name'] = false;
```